# How to avoid com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException: Cannot create XmlPullParser while deseriliazation?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I am getting a exception"Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException: Cannot create XmlPullParser" while deserializing the xml . I have added  following dependency

```
xmlpull_1_0_5.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.4.jar
xstream-1.4.8.jar
```

Test code:

```
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.MarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.UnmarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamReader;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamWriter;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", "chris");
    map.put("island", "faranga");

    XStream magicApi = new XStream();
    magicApi.registerConverter(new MapEntryConverter());
    magicApi.alias("root", Map.class);

    String xml = magicApi.toXML(map);
    System.out.println("Result of tweaked XStream toXml()");
    System.out.println(xml);

    magicApi.fromXML(xml);
    // assert extractedMap.get("name").equals("chris");
    // assert extractedMap.get("island").equals("faranga");

  }

  public static class MapEntryConverter implements Converter {

    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
      return AbstractMap.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {

      AbstractMap map = (AbstractMap) value;
      for (Object obj : map.entrySet()) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) obj;
        writer.startNode(entry.getKey().toString());
        Object val = entry.getValue();
        if (null != val) {
          writer.setValue(val.toString());
        }
        writer.endNode();
      }

    }

    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {

      Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

      while (reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
        reader.moveDown();

        String key = reader.getNodeName(); // nodeName aka element's name
        String value = reader.getValue();
        map.put(key, value);

        reader.moveUp();
      }

      return map;
    }

  }

}
```

Am i misiing some dependency .Any help On this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added `xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar` in place of `xpp3_min-1.1.4.jar`.My program started working

Comment: Thoughtworks should add proper message indicating the real issue. It helps in resolving it. Above jar solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue that is not reported in the stacktrace is that there is a missing resource in xstream 1.4.8

You can detect it only if you attach 1.4.9 source code (1.4.8 source code is strangely not available) and debug.

The real error that is never shown is

```
caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: resource not found: /META-INF/services/org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory make sure that parser implementing XmlPull API is available; nested exception is:
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: resource not found: /META-INF/services/org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory make sure that parser implementing XmlPull API is available
    at org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance(XmlPullParserFactory.java:278)
    at org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance(XmlPullParserFactory.java:259)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppDriver.createParser(XppDriver.java:57)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractXppDriver.createReader(AbstractXppDriver.java:54)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1061)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1052)
    at tudelft.mmi.pn.duo.core.DUOModel.loadFromXml(DUOModel.java:289)
    at tudelft.mmi.pn.duo.core.DUOModel.getNewDUOModel(DUOModel.java:182)
    at domaineditor.extduomodel.ExtDuoModel.<init>(ExtDuoModel.java:56)
    at domaineditor.actions.OpenFile.actionPerformed(OpenFile.java:34)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaMenuItemUI.doClick(AquaMenuItemUI.java:157)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

The real underlying issue seems to be this (known) issue

​https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SMX4-581

Comment: I would recommend you pull-in from the referenced link some further information on how to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem gave me so much headache. I've solved using:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver()); // does not require XPP3 library
XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver()); // does not require XPP3 library starting with Java 6
```

If still problem continues try import these

```
<dependency> 
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId> 
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId> 
        <version>1.4</version> 
</dependency>

<dependency> 
       <groupId>xmlpull</groupId> 
       <artifactId>xmlpull</artifactId> 
       <version>1.1.3.1</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
       <groupId>xpp3</groupId> 
       <artifactId>xpp3_min</ artifactId> 
       <version>1.1.4c</version> 
</dependency>
```

Refs:

https://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html

https://my.oschina.net/u/3067322/blog/821900